# Getting multiple URLs from Firebase Storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

**Needed:** For my app, I need an ArrayList of all urls in a Firebase Storage from a subfolder of said storage.

I have created the reference in which all of the images are located:

```
StorageReference storageRefFemale = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("profileImages").child("femaleProfileImages");
```

**Question:** How do I go about acquiring all of the urls included within? I will add them to an ArrayList:

```
String sitePrefix= "https://";
ArrayList photoArrayFemale = new ArrayList();
photoArrayFemale.add(...); //for each item in the Storage
```

From what I can tell, storageRefFemale.getDownloadUrl() only returns one value. Please advise and please let me know if I should add anything else to the post. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
storageRef.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(
    new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ListResult result) {
            // Iterate over result.items and get the URLs individually.
        }
    }
);
```